# Different MD5 file hash in C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, encoding, md5, checksum

I have a small problem in checking MD5 checksum of files in C# and PHP. The hash calculated by PHP script vary from hash calculated by C#.

```
libcurl.dll C#   = c3506360ce8f42f10dc844e3ff6ed999
libcurl.dll PHP  = f02b47e41e9fa77909031bdef07532af
```

In PHP I use `md5_file` function, and my C# code is:

```
protected string GetFileMD5(string fileName)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
    file.Close();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Any ideas how to calculate the same hash? I think that it may be something about encoding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would bet that C# uses `Windows-1250` encoding while Your PHP script uses `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1` encoding... Try to make the encoding the same on both sides...

Comment: How does it compare against the command line tool `md5sum`?

Comment: with FileStream, you can't be sute that the pointer is at the begening. Use file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) to ensure that's right. All exemple in msdn use it after FileStream constructor.

Comment: @Jack `md5sum` returns `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` but it is a little bit werid, because it's same as md5("")

Comment: @shadyyx PHP does not use any encoding, strings in PHP are same as `byte[]` so there is no need for PHP to decode.

Comment: @Kacper have you checked that you are in fact hashing the same file? I get same hash in PHP and C# just by using your code as is.

Answer (score 1):

My C# is rusty, but will:

```
byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
```

actually read in the entire file? I think it is just hashing the stream object. I believe you need to read the stream, then hash on the entire file contents?

```
  int length = (int)file.Length;  // get file length
  buffer = new byte[length];      // create buffer
  int count;                      // actual number of bytes read
  int sum = 0;                    // total number of bytes read

  // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
  while ((count = file.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
      sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
  byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(buffer);
```

I'm not sure if that actually runs as is, but I think something along those lines will be needed.

Comment: It gives the same result as using ComputeHash.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

I havent had yet any issues with comparison of php md5 with c# md5

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding text = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();                
Convert2.ToBase16(md5.ComputeHash(text.GetBytes(encPassString + sess)));


class Convert2
{
   public static string ToBase16(byte[] input)
   {
      return string.Concat((from x in input select x.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it about file md5? Or just text?

Comment: There is no need to decode the file as text to get a MD5. What if it's not UTF-8?